# JQuery Ajax Call extremely slow in IE compared to other browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

I'm making an AJAX post call to an ASMX web service. In IE11 the calls takes around 3 seconds while in Chrome/Firefox it takes about 0.2 seconds.  The web service itself is doing very little and is almost instant in returning.

My JQuery code is:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",            
            url: "../Chart.asmx/GetData",
            data: "{ID:'" + ID + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("error");
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                 alert("success");
            }
});
```

My Webservice Code (ASMX) is:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public List<DataDTO> GetData(int ID)
{
    return MyClass.Instance.GetData(SessionHelper.CurrentSystem, ID);   
}
```

From logging on the webserver I can see the call takes less than .1 of a second.

As you can I see I'm not doing anything at all complex.  I'm suspicious of enabling session handling.

This is the code from a single panel.  I can have many panels.  If I have 3 panels the execution time for each scales proporionally (e.g. 3 times as long).

Comment: for `IE` 3 secs is lightening speed ;)

Comment: Ha! Even IE should be better than this.

Comment: I've stripped out all the session stuff so it's even more barebones and I'm still having the same issues.

Comment: Ever figure this out?